# ActiveMQ topic messages missed after listener error

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have two separate processes running the same Camel routes the consume from an ActiveMQ topic (i.e.: a topic with multiple subscribers) and occasionally experienced missed messages on one of the consumers.  I want both consumers to receive the same messages, hence why I'm using a topic.

What I *think* is happening is that one of the consumers errors while committing its database transaction because I see a log like this:

```
WARN  arjuna |  || ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff0a666262:e5aa:557ac1a0:14976, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@6dc34434 >
WARN  DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer |  || Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx' - trying to recover. Cause: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
INFO  DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer |  || Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

It appears that while this is going on the consumer in the other process receives another message from the topic and processes it, however this second message is not received by the first consumer (the one that logged the warnings).

I'm far from familiar with the internals of the Spring message listener, but does the connection refresh momentarily make the topic subscription disappear?  Would that explain why broadcast messages are occasionally missed after a listener error?

Does anybody have any suggestions what I might be doing wrong, or are my expectations out of line with how topics are supposed to behave?

Comment: So, what is the expected behavior when a consumer goes down for a while?

Comment: Are you saying that first consumer fails, JMS transaction rolls back and second consumer receives message that was rolled back?

Comment: You need to use durable topics if messages should be persistent for topic listeners that are offline

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I don't know the answer to that question!

Comment: @lkmac No, the first consumer fails on one message and the second consumer then receives a message that the first doesn't

Comment: @ClausIbsen The consumers don't go offline, they are always active

Comment: They don't seem to be always active. :) Nothing is always active, even the sun is going to go offline in a few billion years. :) You have to have a recovery mechanism. The most straightforward way to achieve this is to use jms persistence as suggested by Claus.

Comment: So lifespan of the observable universe aside, the solution is to use durable topics then?  So you'd only ever use non-durable topics for stuff you're happy to lose randomly?  It feels more like a bug in the listener container to me.

Comment: There are many use cases in which it is acceptable to loose messages randomly. For example, if a consumer (or producer, we forgot that side in the discussion) goes down (or an error happens), fetch the latest state from the server and continue listening for new changes.

Comment: Anyway, what's the alternative, how long should the producer keep the messages (in memory, because we are talking about non-durable topics) waiting for the consumer to come back? Forever? (By _forever_ I mean until the sun exhausts all its hydrogen resources, or, more likely to happen before, until the program exhausts all of its available memory :))

Comment: I get your point, but what I don't understand is why the consumer goes away at all.  The service is running continually, the route is running and never suspended or stopped so I don't expect there to be blips where the consumer momentarily vanishes.

Comment: ARJUNA012125 and similar two-phase-commit protocol errors may happen for various reasons. It happened to me once because I did not adjust logging properly and the original exception (some unique key constraint violation) was not logged and I spent hours wondering what's wrong. Maybe you should look for other exceptions that cause JTA transaction to rollback.

Comment: The commit error was the result of a concurrent update, I've tracked that down and have no problem with that.  My problem is that the exception seems to have made the listener disappear briefly, meaning that it missed a couple of messages that were sent to the topic in the meantime.  I might try XA or a transactional consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this info help you:

For a set of messages arriving in order [A, B, C, D] and for two consumers C1 and C2, the normal distribution of messages will be as follows:

C1: [A, C]
C2: [B, D]
Since the broker does not control the work of read processes and the processing order is parallel, it is non-deterministic. If C1 is slower than C2, then the initial set of messages can be processed as [B, D, A, C].

This behavior may surprise newbies who expect messages to be processed in order and build their messaging application on this basis. The requirement that messages sent by the same sender be processed in relative order, also known as causal ordering, is fairly common.

https://habr.com/ru/post/471268/

Comment: Interesting but OP is using broadcast to all the consumers.  And probably does not speak Russian :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a [distributed transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) with the database and activeMQ. The message is only sent if the database transaction success. So a failure in the database can make your message fail.

That's why you see

> nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException

and:

> org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization